# I need to call a function when value is typed in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need to call a function tax when input is typed in a text box and view the result in another textbox. I am using codeigniter and mysql.
I wrote a function tax like

```
<?php
function tax($amount_without_tax, $tax){
   $amount_with_tax = $amount_without_tax + ($tax*($amount_without_tax/100));
   // work out the amount of vat
   $amount_with_tax = round($amount_with_tax, 2);
   return $amount_with_tax;
}
?>
```

And i have a textbox like

```
<input type="number" name="product_price"/>
```

how do i call this function when i type something in the above text box and display them in another textbox
Can someone help me...

Comment: You can either convert the php code to javascript and place it in your page or you can make an Ajax call to do the calculation and return the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function getOrderTotal() {
                var icost = document.myform.myprice.value;

                var itax = getSalesTax();

                var recurrency = '^[0-9]{1,5}\.[0-9]{2}$';
                var reitems = '^([1-9])([0-9]{0,2})$';

                if(!icost.match(recurrency)) {
                    alert('Please provide an item cost in 0.00 format!');
                }
                else {
                    var itotal = (icost) * itax;
                    itotal *= 100;
                    itotal = Math.ceil(itotal);
                    itotal /= 100;
                    if(itotal.toFixed) {
                        itotal = itotal.toFixed(2);
                    }

                    document.getElementById('mytotal').value = itotal;
                }
            }

            function getSalesTax() {
                var taxarray = document.myform.mytax;
                //var retax = '^[1]{1}\.[0-9]{1,4}$';
                var i;

                for(i=0; i<taxarray.length; i++) {
                    if(taxarray[i].checked) {
                        if(!taxarray[i].value) {
                            alert('Please provide a tax rate from the button list only!');
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            return parseFloat(taxarray[i].value);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return 1.0;
            }
        </script>
```

Above is my script
I used text fields and displayed the results

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Wholesale Price</label>
            <div class="controls">
             <input name="myprice" type="text" id="myprice" size="10" maxlength="10" onChange="getOrderTotal()" value="0.00" />

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">

            <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Total amount</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="mytotal" name="mytotal" value="0.00">
              <!--<span class="help-inline">Cost Price</span>-->
            </div>
<div class="control-group">
            <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Tax Details</label>
                        <input name="mytax" type="radio" value="0.145" onClick="getOrderTotal()"/>&nbsp;VAT 
                        <br />
                        <input name="mytax" type="radio" value="0.1725" onClick="getOrderTotal()"/>&nbsp;CST 
                        <br />
                        <input name="mytax" type="radio" value="1.00" onClick="getOrderTotal()" checked="checked"/>&nbsp;Other (no sales tax)
                        </br>
              <!--<span class="help-inline">Cost Price</span>-->
            </div>
          </div>
```

Thank you all for your support.... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a onChange funktion.
`<input  type="number" name="product_price"  onChange = "tax(x,y);"/>`
This schould call your tax funktion if the value of the textbox changed.

Comment: thank you for your support i will work with onChange()

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" name="product_price" id="pro_Price"/>
```

Jquery:

```
$( "#pro_Price" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    //Do your calculation here with this.value

});
```